# ament_target_dependencies vs target_link_libraries

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the [tutorial for adding dependencies](https://docs.ros.org/en/foxy/How-To-Guides/Ament-CMake-Documentation.html#adding-dependencies), it mentions

> Sometimes it will be necessary to call the target_link_libaries CMake function

What are the situations where I should use `ament_target_dependencies` and when should I use `target_link_libraries`?  I also notice that there are occasions where I need both for the dependencies to be correctly added.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/355980/ament_target_dependencies-vs-target_link_libraries/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2020-06-28

Post score: 3

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

From my understanding and a bit of experimentation, `ament_target_dependencies` only works for packages* found using `find_package`.  For packages that aren't coming from `find_package`, e.g. locally compiled libraries in the same package, you will need to use `target_link_libraries`.  See [this question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/98269/linking-library-with-node-in-same-package) for more details.

* Not sure if it's only for ROS packages found with `find_package`, or if it works for any package found that way.

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2021-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-06-02**:
+1 for the finding!

> e.g. locally compiled libraries in the same package,

IMO because that's only a target, let alone a package, during the build-time, being `find_package` incapable makes sense.