# Linking library with node in same package

Tags: ros, ament

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have the following in my CMakeLists.txt

```
project(robot)
...
add_library(${PROJECT_NAME} src/Robot.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(${PROJECT_NAME} rclcpp)

add_executable(node src/node.cpp)
ament_target_dependencies(node ${PROJECT_NAME} ${PROJECT_NAME}_msgs rclcpp) # <--- this line
```

However, when compiling with `colcon build`, it gives the following error

```
ament_target_dependencies() the passed package name 'robot' was not found
```

for the highlighted line.

How do I let nodes use libraries that were compiled in the same package?

With ROS1 catkin, this was done with the following lines

```
add_dependencies(node ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})
target_link_libraries(node ${PROJECT_NAME} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

which I assume is now combined into a single `ament_target_dependencies()`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/371562/linking-library-with-node-in-same-package/) by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1083 on 2021-02-11

Post score: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [this example](https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit2/blob/main/moveit_ros/occupancy_map_monitor/CMakeLists.txt) on creating a library and using it in the same package.

In particular, note that for packages that aren't coming from find_package, e.g. locally compiled libraries in the same package, you will need to use `target_link_libraries`.  See [this answer](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/96375/ament-target-dependencies-vs-target-link-libraries).

In additon, make sure the libraries and packages are installed in the correct location, or else the node will not be able to find the library

```
install(
  TARGETS my_lib
  DESTINATION lib
)

install(
  TARGETS node
  DESTINATION lib/${PROJECT_NAME}
)
```

---

Originally posted by [Rufus](https://answers.ros.org/users/34739/rufus/) with karma: 1083 on 2021-02-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---